# Firebase function to read and write to Firestore throws ReferenceError: query is not defined at cors and Unhandled rejection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a simple booking system whereby a user can select a booking from a web app and the booking should be saved to a Firestore database if the user is validated.

I have made the following test function:

```
exports.BookLesson = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    var bookingId = req.query.bookingId;
    var idToken = query.query.idToken;

    if(bookingId === undefined)
    {
        console.log("Using body params");
        bookingId = req.body.bookingId;
        idToken = query.body.idToken;
    }
    console.log("BookingId: " +bookingId);
    console.log("IdToken: "+idToken);...
```

However all of the parameters are always undefined. After some reading I thought it could be a CORS issue so I tried setting up the Hosting redirect however this had no effect.

Next I tried adding CORS to my function as shown in the Firebase samples provided on GitHub however this then just throws the following errors: 
[image: Firebase errors]

I am a bit lost at what to try now - the documentation around functions seems to be a bit misleading and none of the samples combine a read and write from what I could see. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Appologies for the poor code - I'm from a C++ background!

Full function:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true,
  });
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.BookLesson = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    return cors(req, res, () => {

        var bookingId = req.query.bookingId;
        var year = req.query.year;
        var week = req.query.week;
        var day = req.query.day;
        var idToken = query.query.idToken;

        if(bookingId === undefined)
        {
            console.log("Using body params");
            bookingId = req.body.bookingId;
            year = req.body.year;
            week = req.body.week;
            day = req.body.day;
            idToken = query.body.idToken;
        }

        console.log("BookingId: " +bookingId + " year: " + year + " week: "+ week + " day: " + day);
        console.log("IdToken: "+idToken);

        admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
        .then(decodedToken => {

            const user = admin.auth.getUser(decodedToken.uid);
            console.log("Got User");
            var result = CheckUserValid(user);

            if (result.UserValid) {
                return WriteBooking(result.User, bookingId, year, week, day);
            } else {
                console.log("User not validated to book");
                throw new Error("User not validated to book");
            }

        })
        .catch(reason => {
            res.send(reason)
        });

        console.log("Complete");
        // Send back a message that we've succesfully written the message
        res.json({result: "Complete"});
    });
});

function CheckUserValid(user)
{
    if(!user.emailVerified)
    {
        console.log("User email not verified.");
        return {UserValid: false};
    }

    console.log("Checking validated users db: " + user.uid);

    admin.firestore().collection("ValidatedUsers").doc(user.uid).get()
    .then(snapshot => {

        console.log("Validated user db returned");
        if(snapshot.exists)
        {
            console.log("User validated");
            return {UserValid: true, User: user};
        }
        console.log("Snapshot doesnt exist");
        return {UserValid: false};

    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log("Error getting validated user from db");
        res.send(reason)
    });
}

function WriteBooking(user, bookingId, year, week, day)
{
    console.log("Writing booking for user: "+user.uid);

    admin.firestore().collection("Bookings").doc(year).collection("A").doc("W"+week).collection("D").doc("D"+day).collection("B")
    .doc(bookingId).collection("U").doc(user.uid).set({

        Name: user.displayName,
        Status: "Unverified"

    })
    .then(result => {

        console.log("Document written to Bookings");
        return "Complete.";

    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log("Error getting validated user from db");
        res.send(reason);
    });
}
```

And calling code (Values have been checked and are correct on sending):

```
var bookLessonFunc = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('BookLesson');
    bookLessonFunc({
        bookingId: bookingId,
        year: year,
        week: week,
        day: day,
        idToken: token
    })
    .then(function(result) {

        var message = result.data.result;
        alert(message);

    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Getting the Error details.
      var code = error.code;
      var message = error.message;
      var details = error.details;
      ProcessError("ERROR BOOKING.",error);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

By doing

```
exports.BookLesson = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {...})
```

you define an HTTPS Cloud Function,

but by doing

```
var bookLessonFunc = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('BookLesson');
    bookLessonFunc({....})
    .then(function(result) {...})
```

in your client/front-end, you actually call a Callable Cloud Function.

You should either change your Cloud Function to a Callable one, or call the `BookLesson` HTTPS Cloud Function with [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), for example.

---

For example, the following code with Axios should do the trick (untested). Just change the value of `project-id` with you own project ID.

```
axios.get('https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/BookLesson', {
    params: {
        bookingId: bookingId,
        year: year,
        week: week,
        day: day,
        idToken: token
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

---

**PS:** Take care to return the response only when all the asynchronous operations are complete. Watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) for more details.